# PDF a partir de um PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Qual a forma mais prática e rápida para gerar um relatório PDF a partir de um PHP? Já vi alguns exemplos mas todos muito confusos e sempre usando o mesmo método.

Comment: http://www.fpdf.org/

Answer (score 0):

A forma com que acho mais rápida de gerar arquivos PDF pela linguagem PHP é com a classe TCPDF (http://www.tcpdf.org/) que renderiza o código html e gera o PDF, esta solução é bem simples em comparação as outras por você não ter que escrever novamente para gerar este formato, simplesmente você utiliza o seu código html e pede a classe para renderizar em PDf.

Dê uma conferida neste link http://www.tcpdf.org, a documentação é bastante rica.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: A tua resposta será mais útil se contiver um exemplo prático de como utilizar o sugerido. Da forma que está parece que estás a promover um produto!

Comment: Lendo aqui parece ser mto boa a solução. Vou testar. Grato.

Answer (score 0):

A classe [DOMPDF](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/) é uma boa alternativa para seu propósito

A mesma permite converter HTML para PDF, lendo a sua estrutura DOM.

Abaixo, temos um exemplo extremamente simples de sua utilização

```
<?php
// Inclui a classe DOMPDF
include_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

/**
 * Gera um arquivo PDF lendo o conteúdo HTML proveniente de uma string
 * @param string $titulo Define o título do arquivo PDF
 * @param string $html A string de origem contendo a strutura HTML a ser convertida para PDF
 * @param string $tipo Define o tipo do documento PDF (P = Retrato ou L = Paisagem
 * @return bool Retorna se o arquivo foi gerado com sucesso ou não
 */
function toPDF($titulo, $html, $tipo = "P") {
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();

    // Define internamente o tipo do documento
    if ($tipo == "L") {
        $dompdf->set_paper("legal", "landscape");
    }

    // Carrega o $html de entrada para a classe
    $dompdf->load_html($html); 

    // "Renderiza" o conteúdo
    $dompdf->render();

    // Cria e obtém o PDF gerado
    $pdf = $dompdf->output();

    // Define o caminho onde será salvo
    $arquivo = "arquivos/" . $titulo; 
    return ( file_put_contents($arquivo,$pdf) );
}
?>
```

Modo de uso:

```
<?php
// Html de teste
$html = '
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Teste de HTML</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>Olá, mundo!</div>
        </body>
    </html>
';

// Tenta criar o arquivo PDF
toPDF("arquivo.pdf", $html);
?>
```